# No grub, no terminal blank screen boot 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: 14.04, grub2, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, followed this guide
http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/09/how-to-install-nvidia-352-41-stable-graphics-drivers-in-linux.html 
to install nvidia drivers for my gtx 660. After reboot everything worked fine (even benchmarked in heaven). Then I added Coolbits to the `xorg.conf` since I wanted to oc the gpu a little. But after the restart all that appears is a blank space, no way of opening grub and neither a terminal.
Help please

Is there any way for me to delete the line of new text in `xorg.conf` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH set up, you might be able to log in to the computer from another one and change the xorg.conf that way.